# Access 2007 - Update all rows in a sub form to a calculated field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

My last question was a bit complicated, hopefully someone can get this one for me... I have a calculated field on a sub form, I need to update a bound number field on EVERY ROW on the same subform to equal the calculated sum on the same row whenever ANYTHING on the subform or mainform is changed. The key column is "packno". Calculated field: is "costm3new". The bound field is "cost m3" all are on subform "receive goodssub". `Me.Cost_m3 = Me.Costm3new`works on a field in the subform on lost focus, but I need to make it process that change all the time on any field on sub or main form. 
Thanks in advance, Dan

Comment: I haven't seen your last question but unfortunately this one is still a little difficult to follow, could you upload a screenshot of your form please as this may help?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to write a little routine that updates everything needed to be updated, then call that little subroutine in the AfterUpdate event of all the controls you're concerned about, plus the OnCurrent event of the main and subform.

Maybe that'd be too much code for your situation, but that's what I usually do.